# how to prevent hadoop uploading sames jars to staging cache on each job running

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I just ran different jobs with same jar dependencies' environment in hadoop. And before each job beginning, yarn uploads jobs' own jar files to its staging directory witch has different job id. Since all jar files belonging to each job are same, could I just tell hadoop find them under a common directory instead of uploading them again?

Jar file uploading destination directory look like:
/tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/root/.staging/job_1540620373764_0001/libjars/hadoop-common-2.8.4.jar

Comment: The jars need to be available on the nodemanagers running the code, and applications are only scoped to their current job directory. However, the `hadoop classpath` output should already have at least the hadoop-common jar

Comment: Did you look at the YARN shared cache?  https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/SharedCache.html